# In Python Wing IDE, how to navigate to file from keyboard?

Tags: wing-ide

What is the equivalent of PyCharms "double-shift" shortcut to jump to a file by name? It's a pain to scroll through a list in the Project explorer. I'd rather just type the name and get an autocompletion list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Open from Project** in the **File** menu (or more likely its keyboard equivalent, which depends on keyboard personality but is listed in the menu).  If you want you can bind your own key to the command **open-from-project**.

Related to this are **Find Symbol** and **Find Symbol in Project** in the **Source** menu, which find symbols in your code whose names match the fragment you type.